# Check Registry Version using Perl

Tags: windows, perl, scripting, comparison, registry

I need to go to the registry and check a programs installed version. I am using perl to a whole lot of others things but the registry checking part isn't working. The program version has to be 9.7 and up so it could be 9.8 or 9.7.5.

When I install the program it shows 9.7.4 but I just need the 9.7 to be checked.

Bellow is me going to DisplayVersion which is a REG_SZ which shows 9.7.4.

OR

I could use VersionMajor and VersionMinor together which is a REG_DWORD. Which for Major is 9 and Minor is 7.

```
$ProgVersion= `$rootpath\\system32\\reg\.exe query \\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA} \/v DisplayVersion`;  

if ($ProgVersion == /9.7/)
```

This doesn't work I could make it 9.200 and it still works. I tried to use this instead and it still wouldn't work. This next part is assuming that a new client needs to be install if it goes from 9.7. I was trying to use Great than or equal to, but it didn't work.

```
$ProgVersionMajor= `$rootpath\\system32\\reg\.exe query \\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA} \/v VersionMajor`;  

$ProgVersionMinor= `$rootpath\\system32\\reg\.exe query \\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA} \/v VersionMinor`;  

if (($ProgVersionMajor=~ /9/) && ($ProgVersionMinor=~ /7/))
```

Any help on doing this correctly or fixing what I am doing.

Comment: perhaps you could print out and post here what $ProgVersionMinor etc are

Comment: http://p3rl.org/Win32::TieRegistry#SUMMARY

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

- You don't mention it, but are you using the Perl module [Win32::TieRegistry](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eadamk/Win32-TieRegistry-0.26/lib/Win32/TieRegistry.pm)? If not, you should. It'll make handling the Windows registry much easier.
- In the Perl documentation, you can look at [Version String](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings) under [Scalar Value Constructors](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors). This will make manipulating version strings much, much easier. Version strings have either more than one decimal place in them, or start with the letter `v`. I always prefix them with `v` to make it obvious what it is.

Here's a sample program below showing you how they can be used in comparisons:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;

my $version = v4.10.3;

for my $testVersion (v3.5.2, v4.4.1, v5.0.1) {
    if ($version gt $testVersion) {
        printf qq(Version %vd is greater than test %vd\n), $version, $testVersion;
    }
    else {
        printf qq(Version %vd is less than test %vd\n), $version, $testVersion;
    }
}
```

Note that I can't just print version strings. I have to use `printf` and `sprintf` and use the `%vd` *vector decimal* format to print them out. Printing version strings via a regular `print` statement can cause all sorts of havoc since they're really unicode representations. You put them in a print statement and you don't know what you're getting.

Also notice that you do not put quotes around them! Otherwise, you'll just make them regular strings.

---

## NEW ANSWER

I was trying to find a way to convert a string into a v-string without downloading an optional package like [Perl::Version](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eandya/Perl-Version-1.011/lib/Perl/Version.pm) or (Version), and I suddenly read that v-strings are deprecated, and I don't want to use a deprecated feature.

So, let's try something else...

We could simply divide up version numbers into their constituent components as arrays:

```
v1.2.3 => $version[0] = 1, $version[1] = 2, $version[2] = 3
```

By using the following bit of code:

```
my @version = split /\./, "9.7.5";
my @minVersion = split /\./, "9.7"
```

Now, we can each part of the version string against the other. In the above example, I compare the `9` of @version with the `9` of @version, etc. If `@version` was `9.6` I would have compared the `6` in `@version` against the `7` in `@minVersion` and quickly discovered that `@minVersion` is a higher version number. However, in both the second parts are `7`. I then look at the third section. Whoops! `@minVersion` consists of only two sections. Thus, `@version` is bigger.

Here's a subroutine that does the comparison. Note that I also verify that each section is an integer via the `/^\d+$/` regular expression. My subroutine can return four values:

- `0`: Both are the same size
- `1`: First Number is bigger
- `2`: Second Number is bigger
- `undef`: There is something wrong.

Here's the program:

```
my $minVersion  = "10.3.1.3";
my $userVersion = "10.3.2";

# Create the version arrays

my $result = compare($minVersion, $userVersion);

if (not defined $results) {
    print "Non-version string detected!\n";
}
elsif ($result == 0) {
print "$minVersion and $userVersion are the same\n";
}
elsif ($result == 1) {
print "$minVersion is bigger than $userVersion\n";
}
elsif ($result == 2) {
print "$userVersion is bigger than $minVersion\n";
}
else {
print "Something is wrong\n";
}


sub compare {

my $version1 = shift;
my $version2 = shift;

my @versionList1 = split /\./, $version1;
my @versionList2 = split /\./, $version2;

my $result;

while (1) {

    # Shift off the first value for comparison
    # Returns undef if there are no more values to parse

    my $versionCompare1 = shift @versionList1;
    my $versionCompare2 = shift @versionList2;

    # If both are empty, Versions Matched

    if (not defined $versionCompare1 and not defined $versionCompare2) {
    return 0;
    }

    # If $versionCompare1 is empty $version2 is bigger
    if (not defined $versionCompare1) {
    return 2;
    }
    # If $versionCompare2 is empty $version1 is bigger
    if (not defined $versionCompare2) {
    return 1;
    }
    
    # Make sure both are numeric or else there's an error
    if ($versionCompare1 !~ /\^d+$/ or $versionCompare2 !~ /\^\d+$/) {
    return;
    }

    if ($versionCompare1 > $versionCompare2) {
    return 1;
    }
    if ($versionCompare2 > $versionCompare1) {
    return 2;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No I am not using Win32::TieRegistry. I'm not familiar enough with it to use at this point. I tried to run your code and it fails at the warning at the top. I use `$rootpath\\system32\\reg\.exe query \\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA} \/v DisplayVersion` to get the registry of DisplayVersion. Which when I print it to the file is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA}
    DisplayVersion    REG_SZ    9.5.5.

Comment: I see I could use what you are saying just not getting how to actually do so. I just have to make sure it is at 9.7 or higher.

Comment: Okay, forget the user of version strings... They've been deprecated. See the addition to my answer. As for Win32::TieRegistry, I suggest you give it a try. It's not that hard to use and makes your program a whole lot easier to read. You don't have the `\\\\` all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Win32::TieRegistry

You said in your answer you didn't use `Win32::TieRegistry`. I just want to show you what it can do for the readability of your program:

### Your Way

```
$ProgVersion= `$rootpath\\system32\\reg\.exe query \\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA} \/v DisplayVersion`;
```

### With Win32::TieRegistry

```
use Win32::TieRegistry ( TiedHash => '%RegHash', DWordsToHex => 0 );

my $key = $TiedHash->{LMachine}->{Software}->{Wow6432Node}->{Microsoft}->{Windows}->{CurrentVersion}->{Uninstall}->{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA}->{Version};
my $programValue = $key->GetValue;
my $stringValue = unpack("L", $programValue);
```

Or, you can split it up:

```
my $MSSoftware = $TiedHash->{LMachine}->{Software}->{Wow6432Node}->{Microsoft};
my $uninstall = $MSSoftware->{Windows}->{CurrentVersion}->{Uninstall};
my $programVersion = $uninstall->{9ACB414D-9347-40B6-A453-5EFB2DB59DFA}->{Version};
```

See how much easier that's to read. You can also use this to test keys too.

(***Word 'o Warning***: I don't have a Windows machine in front of me, so I didn't exactly check the validity of the code. Try playing around with it and see what you get.)